# Changing OS time zone does not change JVM default time zone

Tags: java, linux, date, timezone

I'm running a Java program on a Linux machine, however when I use `System.out.println(new Date())`, it always prints the same time zone `(EAT)`, even when I change the link `/etc/localtime` to a different timezone, and the `date` command shows the right timezone (the one referenced by `/etc/localtime`).
I know that `Date.toString()` uses the java  default time zone which must be the same as the host OS time zone, but in my case this is not happening as the JVM default time zone never changes.
My question is: where does Java get the default timezone from; I.e which file or environment variable?

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago), and openjdk 1.7

Comment: It uses the `/etc/timezone` file, from what I understand of the code.

Comment: `java.util.Date` does not have any internal time zone but only uses the time zone of the JVM where its code is run if it is printed by using the method `date.toString()`. Use a suitable formatter for printing your object in the time zone you want.

Comment: In Linux, it uses `/etc/localtime` if `TZ` variable is not set, and there's no `ZONE` entry in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` (it can vary in different distributions, but in RedHat I believe that's it), but maybe [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6456628) is related to your case (not sure). Or maybe you didn't restart your JVM, so it didn't get the new config. Or the code is running in a JVM with the `user.timezone` property set, which overrides the system's config.

Comment: Or maybe some other program running in your JVM changed the JVM’s timezone setting after the JVM was launched (unlikely, but worth mentioning).

Comment: @MenoHochschild I know Date has no time zone; my question is about the default time zone that is used by it's toString

Answer (score 6):

This has all been covered many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

Briefly…

**No, `java.util.Date` does *not* have a time zone.** It is always in UTC. Unfortunately, its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the String, a well-intentioned though unwise anti-feature. Even more confusing: there actually *is* a time zone buried within the `java.util.Date` class, but is irrelevant to this discussion. Confusing? Indeed. These old date-time classes are an awful mess of poor design.

Avoid these troublesome old date-time classes. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Instead of `Date` use `java.time.Instant` for a moment in UTC. For other zones, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

> My question is: where does Java get the default timezone from

Depends on the implementation of Java.

Commonly, the default is to detect the host operating system’s current default time zone and copy that as the JVM’s current default time zone. After the JVM is launched, the two are separated. The host OS may change its default time zone without affecting the JVM. And vice-versa, the JVM may change its current default time zone without affecting the host OS. But, again, this behavior is implementation-dependent as far as I know, and not mandated in the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html).

An argument passed to the JVM during startup may set the initial default time zone, to override detection of the host OS’ default.

**Beware: Unpredictable at runtime** — Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM may at any moment change the JVM’s current default time zone thereby affecting immediately all code of all apps of that JVM.

So for all these reasons, you can see that depending on the default time zone is unwise. Better to always pass the optional `ZoneId` argument to explicitly specify your desired/expected time zone.

Generally best practice is to work, think, store data, and exchange data, all in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Always in UTC.
```

Apply other time zones only when needed such as presentation to the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats when generating or parsing strings. For other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. You can optionally set a time zone on the formatter to be applied dynamically during generation of the String.

Comment: I know Date class does not have a time zone; I've updated my question to be more clear